# Laravel migration primary (or key) "Identifier name is too long"

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration

I have simple Laravel migration file specifying a composite primary key :

```
// ...

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('my_super_long_table_name', function($table)
    {
        $table->integer('column_1');
        $table->integer('column_2');
        $table->integer('column_3');

        $table->primary(['column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3']);
    });
}

// ...
```

And when running `php artisan migrate` this error is thrown :

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1059 Identifier name 'my_super_long_table_name_column_1_column_2_column_3' is too long
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you could specify the exact version you're migrating from and the version you're migrating to.

Comment: Migration in laravel is a file witch define database structure. Not a "real" migration process from a version to another of an app.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Simply specify the key name when creating it (with the second argument for `primary`).

```
$table->primary(['column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3'], 'my_long_table_primary');
```

---

Next,

If you have error like `You have an error in your SQL syntax ...` after this modification please make sure you are not using reserved word by your database engine for your key name.

Eg for MySQL : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html

Tip : `primary` is reserved, so do not use it ;)

Comment: Nice! It also works for foreign keys `$table->foreign('foreign_column', 'fk_name')->references('id')->on('foreign_table');`.

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution: change the collation name of the column

if the column was already created :
add  at the end  ->change()

`public function up()
{
   Schema::create('my_super_long_table_name', function($table)
   {
      $table->integer('column_1')->collation('utf8_general_mysql500_ci');
      $table->integer('column_2')->collation('utf8_general_mysql500_ci');
      $table->integer('column_3')->collation('utf8_general_mysql500_ci');
      $table->primary(['column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3']);
   });
}`